# Strore values in windows Roaming folder in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, outlook-addin

i am developing an Outlook 2013 add-in using C# and MVVM pattern, I have a form where the user must introduce some setting values and I want to store those values in the roaming folder to share them in different machines from which the user may open Outlook. And I don´t know how can I do it. I hope for a little help.

Cheers.

Comment: There are plenty of ressources about Roaming folders : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx . There are links at the bottom with examples.

Answer (score 0):

> i am developing an Outlook 2013 add-in using C#

You may consider using the [StorageItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864182.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from the Outlook object model for storing hidden content/settings. A StorageItem object is stored at the folder level, allowing it to roam with the account and be available online or offline.

The Outlook object model does not provide any collection object for StorageItem objects. However, you can use Folder.GetTable to obtain a Table with all the hidden items in a Folder, when you specify the TableContents parameter as olHiddenItems. If keeping your data private is of a high concern, you should encrypt the data before storing it.
Once you have obtained a StorageItem object, you can do the following to store solution data:

- Add attachments to the item for storage.
- Use explicit built-in properties of the item such as Body to store custom data.
- Add custom properties to the item using UserProperties.Add method. Note that in this case, the optional AddToFolderFields and DisplayFormat arguments of the UserProperties.Add method will be ignored.
- Use the PropertyAccessor object to get or set custom properties.

The default message class for a new StorageItem is IPM.Storage. If the StorageItem existed as a hidden message in a version of Outlook prior to Microsoft Office Outlook 2007, the message class will remain unchanged. In order to prevent modification of the message class, StorageItem does not expose an explicit MessageClass property.

For more information on storing solution data using the StorageItem object, see [Storing Data for Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865327.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize Application Settings for storing these values.  Right-click on your Project, go to Properties, and then Settings to add properties used to configure your program.  Let's say you add a property of type String named `PropName`.  To access it, in your code you would simply just type `Properties.Settings.Default.PropName` to set/get it.